# Visual Studio 2010 breaks HTML formatting

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, formatting, reformatting

Is there any way to get Visual Studio 2010 to properly format HTML code when reformatting?

In HTML,

```
<div><span></span></div>
```

is **different** than

```
<div> <span></span> </div>
```

because of the space after the `<div>`.

Once there is a space, it doesn't matter how many spaces or line breaks there are... so

```
<div> <span></span> </div>
```

is the same as

```
<div> 
    <span></span> 
</div>
```

However, the editor is quite happy to insert or remove spaces/linebreaks between tags. For most cases, that won't matter much, but in some cases, it is critical to control whether there is whitespace between tags.

Similarly, I may want to have `<span> </span>` with space between the tags, but the editor removes that space!

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: This treatment of spaces around tags is correct for XML documents, but a space between HTML tags can be significant.

Comment: Logged for MS at: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/638167/html-editor-adds-removes-spaces-in-the-wrong-places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;` if you want to make sure that space is conserved. Browsers may optimize out empty divs for example (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198058/is-necessary-to-show-an-empty-div)), and containing only whitespace is considered being empty.

Comment: Thanks. Using &nbsp; is a useful strategy and I use it when needed, but my concern applies to other situation.